# How to create folder by Drag and Drop GridView item?

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I want to create one sample, which will drag gridview item and drop it to another item and after that it will create one folder, so if i'll tap on that folder then the two items should display.

Drag and Drop Code

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // do nothing
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        // Code for folder

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
            // save folder?
        }
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        // do nothing
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please kindly go through my and suggest me some solution.

Comment: hey guys can anybody know the answer of this question ???

Comment: what error are you getting while trying to implement it?